# What's the limitation of receivers in JavaMail? How many?

Tags: jakarta-mail

If I use Javamail, can I add hundreds / thouthands / ... receivers to send one email?

What's the best practice please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a limitation to be considered by javamail itself, but rather a limitation of the SMTP server to which javamail delivers its messages.

I suggest rephrasing in terms of the capacity of the SMTP server software that you use, and ask on serverfault.com.